# When Run Rest method the Error "List has no rows for assignment to SObject"

Tags: rest-api

I am trying to get the opportunity Name and a contactID using getContactId() and getOpportunityName() method, just after leadcoversion. I get  "List has no rows for assignment to SObject" error which means no contact or the opportunity was found after the lead was converted. How do I get the contact id and opportunity name once the transaction complete or within the transaction.

```
@HttpPost    
 global static void doConvert()     
 {

    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    Blob body = req.requestBody;
    String bodyString = body.toString();

   //Deserializing the data sent into concrete SFDC objects

    OpportunityUtils jsonwrap = (OpportunityUtils)JSON.deserialize(bodyString,OpportunityUtils.class);
    LIST<Lead> ledID = new LIST<Lead>([Select ID from Lead where ID=:jsonwrap.ID]);

    if(ledID.size()>0)
    {
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(jsonwrap.ID);
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(False); //**IMPORTANT METHOD HERE**

        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        //Contact conID = new Contact();
        //conID = [Select ID,Name from Contact where ID=:lc.getContactId()];
        Opportunity opr=new Opportunity(); 
        opr=
        [Select ID,Name,Opportunity_Type__c,Customer_Type__c,StageName,Build_Type__c,Work_Order_Contact__c,CloseDate,Billing_status__c,Build_Location__c,Order_ID__c,Shipping_Info__c,PO_Number__c,Payment_Type__c,Description from Opportunity where ID=:lc.getOpportunityName()];
        //Get requested parameter one by one
        opr.Name=jsonwrap.JobID;
        opr.Opportunity_Type__c= 'In-House service Bureau';
        opr.Customer_Type__c= 'Existing Customer';
        opr.StageName='Closed Won';
        opr.Build_Type__c= 'Standard';
        //opr.Work_Order_Contact__c = conID.ID;
        opr.CloseDate = jsonwrap.EstimatedCloseDate;
        opr.Billing_status__c =jsonwrap.Status;
        opr.Build_Location__c ='Oakland';
        opr.Order_ID__c=jsonwrap.OrderID;
        opr.Shipping_Info__c=jsonwrap.ShippingMethod;
        opr.PO_Number__c=jsonwrap.CustomerShippingAccountNumber;
        opr.Payment_Type__c=jsonwrap.PaymentMethod;
        //opr.BillingNotes=jsonwrap.BillingNotes;
        opr.Description=jsonwrap.Comments;
        upsert opr;

        RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        // Return a single Lead as an example
        RestContext.response.responseBody = 
        Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize((Opportunity)[Select ID from Opportunity where ID=:opr.ID]));
        RestContext.response.responseBody = 
        Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize((Contact)[Select ID from Contact where ID=:lc.getContactId()]));
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to assign the query result to a list? i.e. `List<Contact> conList = [Select ID,Name from Contact where ID=:lc.getContactId()];`

Comment: if i were you i would check if the leadconversion was successful and then try to grab the contact and opportuntiy info, your code takes into factor that lead conversion will always be a success

Answer (score 0):

try this `conID = [Select ID,Name from Contact where ID=: lcr.getContactId()];`  instead of conID = [Select ID,Name from Contact where ID=:lc.getContactId()];

```
opr=[Select ID,Name,Opportunity_Type__c,Customer_Type__c,StageName,Build_Type__c,Work_Order_Contact__c,CloseDate,Billing_status__c,Build_Location__c,Order_ID__c,Shipping_Info__c,PO_Number__c,Payment_Type__c,Description from Opportunity where ID=:lcr.getOpportunityName()];
```

instead of

```
opr= [Select ID,Name,Opportunity_Type__c,Customer_Type__c,StageName,Build_Type__c,Work_Order_Contact__c,CloseDate,Billing_status__c,Build_Location__c,Order_ID__c,Shipping_Info__c,PO_Number__c,Payment_Type__c,Description from Opportunity where ID=:lc.getOpportunityName()];
```

Comment: check your answer. I don't understand what you wrote there. Maybe you mixed up with formatting...

Answer (score 0):

I gave up using SOQL for one object. Even if I state Id = :objectId in where clause I assign result to a list of objects.
Instead of

```
sObject obj = [SELECT Id FROM sObject WHERE Id = :sObjectId];
```

use

```
List<sObject> objs = [SELECT Id FROM sObject WHERE Id = :sObjectId];
if (objs.size() == 1) {
 // logic goes here
}
```

---

May the Force.com be with you!